# Calculate average from list of values in JSON

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple ng-repeat that displays a list of values (financial income). How can i calculate the average from this list?

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData">
    {{ data.income }}
</div>
<div>
    Average:
</div>
```

Which displays:

```
11
14
8
9
21
10
2
1
5
13
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In HTML

```
Average: {{calculateAverage(MyData)}}
```

Code

```
$scope.calculateAverage = function(MyData){ 
    var sum = 0; 
    for(var i = 0; i < MyData.length; i++){
        sum += parseInt(MyData[i], 10); //don't forget to add the base 
    }

    var avg = sum/MyData.length;

    return avg; 
};
```

Comment: You're commenting out the closing bracket on the for loop there too

Comment: What about if `MyData.length` is `0`?

Comment: @tomasbedrich if myData.length == 0 then 0 < 0 is false and it will skip the for loop.  The problem is when you get to var avg = 0/0 which is 'undefined'

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to write a function which takes as argument the integer array and returns the average.

Most suggestions here assign the function to the $scope in your controller, however, I would create a $filter for reusability across your app as a utility.

```
(function(angular) {

    function average($log) {
        return function(array) {
            if (!angular.isArray(array) || array.length === 0) {
                $log.error("Expect array.");
                return;
            }

            var sum = 0;
            angular.forEach(array, function(value) {
                if (!angular.isNumber(value)) {
                    $log.error("Expect number.");
                    return;
                }
                sum += value; 
            });

            return sum / array.length;     
        };
    }

    angular
        .module("yourAppName")
        .filter("average", ["$log", average]);

})(angular);
```

You can now inject $filter anywhere in your Angular code and use the function by the "average" namespace.

```
angular
    .module("yourAppName")
    .controller("yourCtrl", ["$filter", "$scope", function($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.MyData = {
            income: [], // your integer array
            average: $filter("average")($scope.MyData.income); 
        };
    }]);
```

Or right in the HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData">
    {{ data }}
</div>
<div>
    Average: {{ MyData | average }}
</div>
```

Comment: But isn't your filter expecting an array when that HTML is sending an integer?  And also, isn't the last "data" outside the ng-repeat loop?

Comment: Typo in the HTML. Assuming MyData is an array of integers and not a collection of objects, you would ng-repeat over MyData and passed MyData to the average filter.

If MyData were a structure like the Controller example, then you'd iterate over MyData.income and output MyData.average outside the ng-repeat block.

Comment: Since none of these examples consider that his array is a collection, he's better off changing his structure or writing a function to accept a collection and sum the .income property.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is related to AngularJS.
You need to create a function who calculates your average and then :

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData">
    {{ data.income }}
</div>
<div>
    Average: {{ myAveragingFunction(MyData) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Probably the parameter of myAverageFunction should be "MyData", not "data", like "myAveragingFunction(MyData)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library for calculation averages and other data processing.

This is a code of controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.MyData = [{income:1000}, {income:2000}];

     $scope.avgIncome = function() {
         return alasql('SELECT VALUE AVG(income) FROM ?',[$scope.MyData]);
     };
};
```

And HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in MyData">
    {{ data.income }}
</div>
<div>
    Average: {{avgIncome()}}
</div>
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/she06Lq3/2/) at jsFiddle.